# Does disabling "restart and shut down" under the remote management options do nothing?

Tags: macos, mojave, remote-desktop, screen-sharing

I've got a Mac running Mojave and under the System Preferences > Sharing > Remote Management I've checked "Allow access for: only these users". I've added the account name of my remote user and under "options" set the following settings:

[image: Settings]

It seems logical that disabling "restart and shut down" would prevent the remote user from restarting or shutting down the machine, however in practice they can freely restart and shutdown the Mac once they've connected to the screen share.

Is this expected behaviour? Is there any way to completely prevent the screen sharing user from shutting down the machine, in case I'm logged in at the same time?

Comment: How are they shutting down the machine?  Via menu or via Terminal command?

Comment: @Allan - just via the Apple menu and the regular "shut down" menu item. I actually have two separate macs with this setup and the same problem occurs on both, so it's not a unusual quirk - it seems to be the default behaviour.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you jumped to the conclusion of it not being "an unusual quirk" and that "it's the default behavior."  At first glance, it appears to be a *bug.*   That said, is the user that you've granted remote access/control to an admin?  Have you tried it with a non-admin user?

Comment: @Allan - I mean that it's not due to a quirk of one individual machine's configuration. The remote user does not have an admin role.

Comment: Then it definately sounds like a bug - a regular user shouldn't be able to shutdown a machine they are connected to remotely.  Start off by filing a a report:  https://www.apple.com/feedback/macos.html

Comment: IMOH this is no bug at all. Disabling restart/shutdown only disables the possibility to restart/shutdown a remote host from **within** ARD (menu > Manage > Restart...|Shutdown...)! If you can **observe > control** a remote host it is still possible to perform these tasks in the screen window.